# Can we use voice command for interaction in iPhone App

Tags: iphone, voice-recognition

Is there any api or method available for integrating voice command in iPhone app for simple operations like going next and previous? I doubt that it is available but I need clarification on this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing provided by the iOS Library. Not for the regular voice commands and not for Siri. This might change with the upcoming version, but there's nothing announced yet.

Even on [CocoaPods](http://cocoapods.org/?q=voice) there's no such library avaliable, so I think you might have to buy something or start from scratch